# Solve Jest test error from Webpack plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I've webpack config file that contains some configuration strings such as:

```js
const config={
    'accessUrl': 'http://localhost:8000/links',
    'firstAuthUrl': 'http://localhost:8000/firstAccess',
    'baseUrl': '/video?url=',
    'urlRefreshToken': 'http://localhost:8000/refreshAccessToken',
    'loginUrl': 'http://localhost:8000/login',
    'userUrl':'http://localhost:8000/user'
}

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new DefinePlugin({
            'config': JSON.stringify(config)
        }),
    ],
});
```

And it's ok, but when i add a jest test to one component that inside use config (read above), it doesn't work, because it doesn't recognize config.

The part of component is that:

```html
<a href={config.baseUrl} className='btn btn-outline-warning justify-content-center mt-5'>
```

When I start the app it work, but when I write and launch the test:

```
describe('Content Component', () => { 
  const content = shallow(<Content {...props}/>); expect(content.render); 
  expect(content.find('.content')).toBeDefined(); 
})
```

When the test run say: `ReferenceError: config is not defined`

How can I solve?

Thank's of all.

Comment: Sorry, the component part is that: <a href={config.baseUrl} className='btn btn-outline-warning justify-content-center mt-5'>

Comment: It doesn't work ? What does it actually says? Something like `Unexpected token` ?

Answer (score 2):

Jest actually do not use webpack and it's config. Therefore `DefinePlugin` can't provide `config` for Jest and results in the error you have mentioned.

To fix the situation you have to provide the same config from `DefinePlugin` in Jest configuration under `globals`. Ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globals-object

Sample `jest` config:

```
const { jsWithTs: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets');
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/app'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    transform: {
        ...tsjPreset.transform,
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
    globals: {
        config: *YOUR_CONFIG_HERE*
    },
};
```

Comment: Have you any exmample?

Comment: Updated answer cause formatting does not work in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve with add setupTest.js file like:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


const config = {
    baseUrl:""
};

global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
global.config = config;
```